# CODEIGNITER: dynamically get drop down list but first to appear in list is the selected value

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have a table category that consist of (Dessert,Halal,Vegetarian). i was trying to create a CRUD. now i select the Dessert in my drop down list so i want to fetch all the value in my drop down but i want the Dessert to be seen first in dropdown. this is my code:

VIEW:

```
 <?php $product_id = $product['recipe_id']; ?>
 <?php echo form_open("dashboard/edit_product/$product_id");?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Recipe Name: </td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($r_name);?>
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Recipe Category: </td>
        <td><select name="r_category">
              <option value=""><?php echo $r_category['value'];?></option>
            </select>.
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Recipe Description: </td>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea($r_description); ?>
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Recipe Cooking Time: </td>
        <td><select name="cooking_time">
              <option value=""><?php echo $cooking_time['value'];?></option>
            </select>.
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Recipe Calories: </td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($r_cal);?>
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Recipe Serving Size: </td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($r_serve);?>
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>Recipe Procedure: </td>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea($r_procedure); ?>
        <div class="cleaner h10"></div></td>
    </tr>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
            <input type="button" name="btnBack" id="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard'" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  function edit_product($product_id) {
    $product = $this->products_model->get_product($product_id);

    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $this->data['title'] = 'Edit Recipe';

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('r_name', 'Recipe name', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('r_description', 'Recipe description', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('r_cal', 'Recipe Calories', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('r_serve', 'Recipe Serving Size', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('r_procedure', 'Recipe procedure', 'required|xss_clean');



    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {       
        $data = array(
            'r_name'                => $this->input->post('r_name'),
            'r_category'            => $this->input->post('r_category'),
            'r_description'         => $this->input->post('r_description'),
            'cooking_time'          => $this->input->post('cooking_time'),
            'r_cal'                 => $this->input->post('r_cal'),
            'r_serve'               => $this->input->post('r_serve'),
            'r_procedure'           => $this->input->post('r_procedure'),

        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
        {
            $this->products_model->update_product($product_id, $data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Recipe updated successfully.</p>");

            redirect(base_url().'dashboard/edit_product/'.$product_id);
        }           
    }

    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

    $this->data['product'] = $product;

    //display the edit product form
    $this->data['r_name'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_name',
            'id'        => 'r_name',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     =>  $this->form_validation->set_value('r_name', $product['r_name']),
        );      
        $this->data['r_image'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_image',
            'id'        => 'r_image',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     =>  $this->form_validation->set_value('r_image', $product['r_image']),
        );  
        $this->data['r_category'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_category',
            'id'        => 'r_category',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     =>  $this->form_validation->set_value('r_category', $product['r_category']),
        );          
        $this->data['r_description'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_description',
            'id'        => 'r_description',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('r_description', $product['r_description']),
        );
        $this->data['cooking_time'] = array(
            'name'      => 'cooking_time',
            'id'        => 'cooking_time',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('cooking_time', $product['cooking_time']),
        );
        $this->data['r_cal'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_cal',
            'id'        => 'r_cal',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('r_cal', $product['r_cal']),
        );
        $this->data['r_serve'] = array(
            'name'      => 'r_serve',
            'id'        => 'r_serve',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'style'     => 'width:300px;',
            'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('r_serve', $product['r_serve']),
        );
        $this->data['r_procedure'] = array(
            'name'  => 'r_procedure',
            'id'    => 'r_procedure',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'style' => 'width:300px;',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('r_procedure', $product['r_procedure']),
        );

    //var_dump($this->data);
    $this->load->view('edit_product', $this->data);
}
```

model:

```
function get_product($product_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('recipe_id', $product_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('recipe');

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: i think you can try to update a record isn't it?